# Dragging files delay in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop

A week ago I reinstalled Windows 10 (the problem occurred before as well) and now every time I try to drag a file (no matter what hard drive I use), there is a delay before the file snap to the cursor.

There is 1 to 2 second delay before the file magically appear behind my cursor.

I checked the CPU usage and it's not the issue (even when there is 1% usage it still happens), I don't use "ClickLock" (saw an answer about that so just wanted to clear it out) and I restarted my computer and it return's after a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem should be caused by the third party context menu extension installed in the system.

To fix this problem, we need to disable or remove the third party context menu extension from the system.  There is a tool called ShellExView, which can help find out what third party context menu extensions are installed in the system and help us disable them easily.

You can get the tool from the link: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html#DownloadLinks (If your Windows 10 system is an 64 bit system, please download the x64 version in the same page)

1. Once you download the tool (it should be a ZIP file), extract the zip file to a local folder. Find the execute file (shexview.exe) of the tool in the extracted folder.
2. Right click the execute file (shexview.exe), and then choose “Run as Administrator”
3. From the menu, click on Options then click on Filter by Extension Type,  let’s only select Context Menu in the list, then click OK.
4. Now, the tool only list the Context Menu extensions in the list, you can find the Extension name, Type, Description, Version, Product name and Company.
5. The items marked with pink color should be installed by third party software. Also, you can check the Product Name and Company column in the list. The default system context menu’s company should be Microsoft Corporation.
6. Select the third party context menu extension, then click the red button under the menu bar to disable them.

Once the you have the disable the third party context menu extension above, please double check the list and make sure third party context menu extension’s status in Disabled column is Yes.

Meanwhile, since the context menu extension is associated with Windows Explorer, it is recommend to restart your computer to check the result.

It should be fixed after a system restart.

Comment: For now it's working :) If it keep working for the rest of the day I will accept the answer :) Thanks!

Comment: The problem came back :\ I don't know what to do :\

Comment: Thanks, no need to restart PC, end explorer.exe process from the task manager and open it again. Or just go to options in the ShelExViewer and "restart explorer".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like restarting explorer.exe solve the problem until the first computer restart. But, for me the final solution was turning off custom scale for primary display. Everything is working fine now.